# compliling multi-path with make results in "No rule to make target" errors

Tags: c, linux, makefile

when I tried to compile a program with make, something wrong occurs with the following code:

```
INC_DIR = ./include
BIN_DIR = ./bin
SRC_DIR = ./src1 ./src2 ./src3
OBJ_DIR = ./obj

SRC = $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,${OBJ_DIR}/%.o,$(notdir ${SRC}))
TARGET1 = main
BIN_TARGET1 = ${BIN_DIR}/${TARGET1}
 CC = gcc
 CFLAGS = -g -Wall -I${INC_DIR}
 CFLAGS += -DLOG_USE_COLOR
 ${BIN_TARGET1}:${OBJ}
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@
${OBJ_DIR}/%.o:$(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIR),$(dir)/%.c)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm -rf ${BIN_TARGET1}
    rm -rf ${OBJ_DIR}/*.o
    @echo ${SRC}
```

With make, the result is:
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/main.o', needed by 'bin/main'.  Stop. Do not understand what problem is.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's poorly formatted CC till ${BIN_TARGET}) should be all the way to the left.  How do you call make?  Do you have a src/main.c?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I've formatted the code, Yes, there is "src1/main.c" indeed. If I  do not use foreach iteration and only compile the C profiles in one single path. That is fine. I guess this problem  may be cause by the foreach iterations : SRC = $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c));   ${OBJ_DIR}/%.o:$(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIR),$(dir)/%.c)

Comment: I just input "make" in the  linux terminator opened in the same path level as makefile.

Comment: Please edit question so it reflect the current state of your makefile.

Comment: It's overly complicated, btw, just use VPATH to list where to find the source files, or consider using a single directory instead.  If you ever have a duplicate source file name in any of src directory you will overwrite one of them in obj.

Comment: Note that make is trying to build `obj/main.o` but your definition of OBJ_DIR will result in `./obj/main.o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `${OBJ_DIR}/%.o:$(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIR),$(dir)/%.c)`, when applied to main.o, says that `main.o` depends on `src1/main.c`, `src2/main.c` *and* `src3/main.c` so even `make obj/main.o` will fail with:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/main.o'.  Stop.
```

Here are 3 alternatives:

1. Use separate rules:

```
${OBJ_DIR}/%.o: src1/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
${OBJ_DIR}/%.o: src2/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
${OBJ_DIR}/%.o: src3/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

You can use a template to generate these (left as exercise for user).

2. Use VPATH to specify which directories to find your source files:

```
SRC_DIR = ./src1 ./src2 ./src3
VPATH = $(SRC_DIR)

${OBJ_DIR}/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

3. Consider using a single `src/` directory to avoid possible future name clash when you compile files from 3 different directories into `obj/`.

Comment: You don't need to use the `subst` for `:` chars.  The docs say: _In the 'VPATH' variable, directory names are separated by colons or blanks._

Comment: @MadScientist Revised as suggested.  I must have messed up the test when I used space and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @ Allan Wind. Thanks for the kind reply. I will try these solutions provided as later!

Comment: All the solutions work! Thanks alot!

Comment: @BowinChow Great.  Please click the check mark next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: @Allan Wind. Accepted.

Comment: @BowinChow Yes, I know, and that is all you have to do to thank someone that answers your question next time.

Comment: @Allan Wind. Thanks! I am a fresh man to stackoverflow. Appreciate it much that you could tell me the tips~~~~~